# Return the rows which sum of qty column is bigger than

Tags: mysql, sql, having

The table1 is a simple version of the source table but for example its enough. My point is to return all rows with **locator** and **lot** where the **given partnumber**(*H28650-D3830-EX*) matches and the given **sum qty**(62) is eligible for that order.

In case below It should return two rows. (*62 > 60 so 60+60=120 > 62 - two rows*)

Unfortunately the query does not return anything. Can someone help me with that issue, I want to know the logic behind it.

```
select partnumber,locator,lot,qty from table1 
where partnumber = 'H28650-D3830-EX'
group by partnumber,locator,lot,qty
Having sum(qty) > 62;
```

[image: table1]

Thanks to people who will try to help me :)

Comment: The first step to solving this is computing a running total. Write the select query that will show the running total in it's own column first, and then writing a WHERE clause to target that column will be easy. Having said that much, I feel like this is one of those situations where I can do more good for you by asking you to Google that solution on your own.

Comment: No, I believe you used Google. What I did for you was tell you what to look for on Google, so your search can be much more productive.

Comment: SQL is a language. Please tag your database and version. The reason your query doesn't return anything is because your are grouping by all the columns. When you say sum(qty), you need to clarify what level of aggregation that is (per partnumber and locator?)

Comment: Remove `qty` from the select list and group by.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn thank for the running total thing, I havent heard about it until today, now I managed to solve my problem. Thanks !